# Iterate over a layers' features and render the PNG for each feature

Tags: pyqgis

I have a vector layer with about 2500 features, each feature is of a square shape and i need to get each feature as a PNG. I have rendered the PNG for the layer as a whole, but I've been unable to export each individual feature. The code works exactly as it should if there was only one feature in the layer. What would be the most optimum method without having to create individual layers for all my 2500 features.

```
def finished():
    img = render.renderedImage()
    # save the image; img.save("C:\QGIS Project\Restructured\Rev1\\test_render.png","png")
    img.save(f'C:\QGIS Project\Restructured\Rev1\\test_render_{feature[0]}.png', "png")

layer = QgsProject.instance().mapLayersByName("Rotated")[0]
settings = QgsMapSettings()
settings.setLayers([layer])
settings.setBackgroundColor(QColor(255, 255, 255))
settings.setOutputSize(QSize(400, 400))
features = layer.getFeatures()
settings.setExtent(layer.extent())

for feature in features:
    render = QgsMapRendererParallelJob(settings)
    render.finished.connect(finished)
    # Start the rendering
    render.start()
    render.waitForFinished()
```

Comment: Atlas: https://docs.qgis.org/3.4/en/docs/training_manual/forestry/forest_maps.html

Comment: Thank you @BERA, I feel like there has to be an easier way tweaking this code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try moving the `setExtent()` call on the `QgsMapSettings` object inside your loop and pass the bounding box of the current feature's geometry on each iteration:

```
def finished():
    img = render.renderedImage()
    # save the image; img.save("C:\QGIS Project\Restructured\Rev1\\test_render.png","png")
    img.save(f'C:\QGIS Project\Restructured\Rev1\\test_render_{feature[0]}.png', "png")

layer = QgsProject.instance().mapLayersByName("Rotated")[0]
settings = QgsMapSettings()
settings.setLayers([layer])
settings.setBackgroundColor(QColor(255, 255, 255))
settings.setOutputSize(QSize(400, 400))

for feature in layer.getFeatures():
    layer.setSubsetString("fid = {}".format(feature.id()))
    settings.setExtent(feature.geometry().boundingBox())
    render = QgsMapRendererParallelJob(settings)
    render.finished.connect(finished)
    # Start the rendering
    render.start()
    render.waitForFinished()

layer.setSubsetString("")
```

By the way, if you wish to add a small margin around each feature's extent you can use the `grow()` method on the `QgsRectangle` object returned by `feature.geometry().boundingBox()`. So your loop block could look like:

```
for feature in layer.getFeatures():
    layer.setSubsetString("fid = {}".format(feature.id()))
    extent = feature.geometry().boundingBox()
    extent.grow(0.01) # Play with the value to find a suitable margin
    settings.setExtent(extent)
    render = QgsMapRendererParallelJob(settings)
    render.finished.connect(finished)
    # Start the rendering
    render.start()
    render.waitForFinished()
```

Comment: This is what i was looking for, but in doing this the png will include other overlapping features. When iterating through the features is it possible to render just that feature so the other overlapping features wont get in the way?

Comment: @Aditha Iddamlgoda, adding a call to `layer.setSubsetString("fid = {}".format(feature.id()))` should do the trick. Please try the updated script in my answer.